# Progress when assigning datasource to XtraTreeList

Tags: treeview, devexpress

I have a XtraTreeList and I assign a huge datasource (with millions of items) to it

```
xtraTree.TreeViewData = dataSource;
```

This operation takes 80 seconds to complete, which is totally fine given the amount of nodes.

I'd just like to display a somewhat reliable progress bar to the user, indicating how many nodes have been processed.

I have tried:

- looking in the event list, but I only found `PrintExportProgress`
- googling for the topic, hoping I would find something on the DevExpress support pages

I'm using the WinForms variant, version 15.2 if that matters.

This is not about displaying progress while I build the datasource. There are 2 steps:

- build the datasource (read from file) - this also takes 60 seconds, but I do that myself and I have no problem here
- assign the datasource to the XtraTreeList - works, but I don't get progress information and it needs to be done on the UI thread, which is blocking

This is also not about cross-thread updating of the progress bar. I know how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I did the same thing in a project that I built using WinForms ... except I only had 4500 items - these items were files that I had to extract data from.  What I did is at each file that I processed (at the bottom of my foreach loop) I called a method to update my progress bar on my form:

```
Form1.UpdateProgressbar();
```

Inside my Form1.cs, I did this:

```
public void UpdateProgressbar()
    {

        progressBar2.Increment(1);
        label7.Text = "Processed: " + Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Value) + " out of " + Globals.totalartistcount + " Artists";
        label8.Text = "Processed: " + Globals.songcounter + " Songs.      Processing: " + Globals.artist;
        label9.Text = "Total Number of Songs to process: " + Globals.totalsongcount;

        progressBar2.Update();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

If I remember right the

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

was critical to actually see the progress bar move and the labels update their text.  I initialized my progress bar this way:

```
       /* ------ progress bar ------------------------------------------ */

    public void InitializeProgressBar(DirectoryInfo di)
    {
        int songcount = 0;
        int artistcount = 0;
        int index = 0;



        //Get Total number of folders
        foreach (var sf in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            //find index of artist to process
            //this is just an array of artist names and if true or false to process
            for (int i = 0; i <= Globals.artists.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                if (sf.Name == Globals.artists[i, 0])
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (Globals.artists[index, 1] != "false")
            {
                // Get a total number of files to process (MAX)
                foreach (var fi in sf.GetFiles("*.mp3"))
                {
                    songcount++;
                }
                artistcount++;

            }
        }

        Globals.totalartistcount = artistcount;
        Globals.totalsongcount = songcount;
        progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar2.Maximum = artistcount - 1;
        progressBar2.Value = 0;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

There, I hope that helps.

Comment: Where exactly is this using a DevExpress TreeList and assigning a datasource?